# Fatal error calling to undefined function in PHP file

Tags: php

I am trying to implement a login system in a web site.

This is the file structure:

-main_login.php

-checklogin.php

-includes/functions.php

-includes/loginform.php

This project is working fine on my server, but today I have migrated all files to a new server, and now I am getting following error at checklogin.php:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_verify() in /includes/loginform.php on line 55

And at file loginform.php the error message is:
Fatal error: Class 'DbConn' not found in /includes/loginform.php on line 4

What should I change? I have only migrated all files to a new server.

These are the files:

**checklogin.php**

```
// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$username = $_POST['myusername'];
$password = $_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);

$response = '';
$loginCtl = new LoginForm;
$conf = new GlobalConf;
$lastAttempt = checkAttempts($username);
$max_attempts = $conf->max_attempts;


//First Attempt
if ($lastAttempt['lastlogin'] == '') {

    $lastlogin = 'never';
    $loginCtl->insertAttempt($username);
    $response = $loginCtl->checkLogin($username, $password);

} elseif ($lastAttempt['attempts'] >= $max_attempts) {

    //Exceeded max attempts
    $loginCtl->updateAttempts($username);
    $response = $loginCtl->checkLogin($username, $password);

} else {

    $response = $loginCtl->checkLogin($username, $password);

};

if ($lastAttempt['attempts'] < $max_attempts && $response != 'true') {

    $loginCtl->updateAttempts($username);
    $resp = new RespObj($username, $response);
    $jsonResp = json_encode($resp);
    echo $jsonResp;

} else {

    $resp = new RespObj($username, $response);
    $jsonResp = json_encode($resp);
    echo $jsonResp;

}

unset($resp, $jsonResp);
ob_end_flush();
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
//Class Autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {

    $className = strtolower($className);
    $path = "includes/{$className}.php";

    if (file_exists($path)) {

        require_once($path);

    } else {

        die("The file {$className}.php could not be found.");

    }
});

function checkAttempts($username)
{

    try {

        $db = new DbConn;
        $conf = new GlobalConf;
        $tbl_attempts = $db->tbl_attempts;
        $ip_address = $conf->ip_address;
        $err = '';

        $sql = "SELECT Attempts as attempts, lastlogin FROM ".$tbl_attempts." WHERE IP = :ip and Email = :username";

        $stmt = $db->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip_address);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;

        $oldTime = strtotime($result['lastlogin']);
        $newTime = strtotime($datetimeNow);
        $timeDiff = $newTime - $oldTime;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        $err = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();

    }

    //Determines returned value ('true' or error code)
    $resp = ($err == '') ? 'true' : $err;

    return $resp;

};

function mySqlErrors($response)
{
    //Returns custom error messages instead of MySQL errors
    switch (substr($response, 0, 22)) {

        case 'Error: SQLSTATE[23000]':
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>Username or email already exists</div>";
            break;

        default:
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>An error occurred... try again</div>";

    }
};
```

**loginform.php**

```
<?php

class LoginForm extends DbConn
{
    public function checkLogin($myusername, $mypassword)
    {


        $conf = new GlobalConf;
        $ip_address = $conf->ip_address;
        $login_timeout = $conf->login_timeout;
        $max_attempts = $conf->max_attempts;
        $timeout_minutes = $conf->timeout_minutes;
        $attcheck = checkAttempts($myusername);
        $curr_attempts = $attcheck['attempts'];

        $datetimeNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $oldTime = strtotime($attcheck['lastlogin']);
        $newTime = strtotime($datetimeNow);
        $timeDiff = $newTime - $oldTime;

        try {

            $db = new DbConn;
            $tbl_members = $db->tbl_members;
            $err = '';

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            $err = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();

        }

        $stmt = $db->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_members." WHERE email = :myusername");
        $stmt->bindParam(':myusername', $myusername);
        $stmt->execute();

        // Gets query result
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);






        if ($curr_attempts >= $max_attempts && $timeDiff < $login_timeout) {

            //Too many failed attempts
            $success = "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>Has superado el n�mero m�ximo permitido de intentos... favor de esperar ".$timeout_minutes." minutos antes de intentarlo otra vez</div>";

        } else {

             //If max attempts not exceeded, continue
            // Checks password entered against db password hash
            if (password_verify($mypassword, $result['password']) && $result['verified'] == '1') {

                //Success! Register $myusername, $mypassword and return "true"
                $success = 'true';
                    session_start();

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
                    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $result['nombre']." ".$result['apellidos'];
                    $_SESSION['foto'] = $result['foto_usuario'];
                    $_SESSION['nivel'] = $result['nivel_usuario'];
                    $_SESSION['cargo'] = $result['cargo_usuario'];
                    $_SESSION['nivel'] = $result['nivel_usuario'];
                    $_SESSION['agencia'] = $result['agencia_usuario'];
                    $_SESSION['desde'] = $result['mod_timestamp'];



            } elseif (password_verify($mypassword, $result['password']) && $result['verified'] == '0') {

                //Account not yet verified
                $success = "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>Your account has been created, but you cannot log in until it has been verified</div>";

            } else {

                //Wrong username or password
                $success = "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>ERROR, usuario o contrase�a no correctos</div>";

            }
        }
        return $success;
    }

    public function insertAttempt($username)
    {
        try {
            $db = new DbConn;
            $conf = new GlobalConf;
            $tbl_attempts = $db->tbl_attempts;
            $ip_address = $conf->ip_address;
            $login_timeout = $conf->login_timeout;
            $max_attempts = $conf->max_attempts;

            $datetimeNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $attcheck = checkAttempts($username);
            $curr_attempts = $attcheck['attempts'];

            $stmt = $db->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$tbl_attempts." (ip, attempts, lastlogin, email) values(:ip, 1, :lastlogin, :username)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip_address);
            $stmt->bindParam(':lastlogin', $datetimeNow);
            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $curr_attempts++;
            $err = '';

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            $err = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();

        }

        //Determines returned value ('true' or error code)
        $resp = ($err == '') ? 'true' : $err;

        return $resp;

    }

    public function updateAttempts($username)
    {
        try {
            $db = new DbConn;
            $conf = new GlobalConf;
            $tbl_attempts = $db->tbl_attempts;
            $ip_address = $conf->ip_address;
            $login_timeout = $conf->login_timeout;
            $max_attempts = $conf->max_attempts;
            $timeout_minutes = $conf->timeout_minutes;

            $att = new LoginForm;
            $attcheck = checkAttempts($username);
            $curr_attempts = $attcheck['attempts'];

            $datetimeNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $oldTime = strtotime($attcheck['lastlogin']);
            $newTime = strtotime($datetimeNow);
            $timeDiff = $newTime - $oldTime;

            $err = '';
            $sql = '';

            if ($curr_attempts >= $max_attempts && $timeDiff < $login_timeout) {

                if ($timeDiff >= $login_timeout) {

                    $sql = "UPDATE ".$tbl_attempts." SET attempts = :attempts, lastlogin = :lastlogin where ip = :ip and email = :username";
                    $curr_attempts = 1;

                }

            } else {

                if ($timeDiff < $login_timeout) {

                    $sql = "UPDATE ".$tbl_attempts." SET attempts = :attempts, lastlogin = :lastlogin where ip = :ip and email = :username";
                    $curr_attempts++;

                } elseif ($timeDiff >= $login_timeout) {

                    $sql = "UPDATE ".$tbl_attempts." SET attempts = :attempts, lastlogin = :lastlogin where ip = :ip and email = :username";
                    $curr_attempts = 1;

                }

                $stmt2 = $db->conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':attempts', $curr_attempts);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':ip', $ip_address);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':lastlogin', $datetimeNow);
                $stmt2->bindParam(':username', $username);
                $stmt2->execute();

            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            $err = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();

        }

        //Determines returned value ('true' or error code) (ternary)
        $resp = ($err == '') ? 'true' : $err;

        return $resp;

    }

}
```

Comment: The declaration of `function password_verify()` is not in any of these files.

Comment: @marekful, it is a PHP function http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php, I guess the new server an old PHP version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your PHP version may be out of date (you mentioned you have recently switched hosting). [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for the `password_verify()` function states it is available for versions **5.5.0** and over.

You can check the current PHP version by running the following PHP code on a page:

```
<?php phpversion(); ?>
```

If needed, you may need your host to upgrade the PHP version for you (and it's generally a good idea for security etc.)